# ASP .NET MVC e JavaScript - Abrir modal com ID do objeto selecionado em uma lista

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, modal

**PERGUNTA INICIAL**

Estou trabalhando em um projeto ASP .NET MVC com bootstrap e preciso abrir um modal para edição e exclusão de registros de uma listagem.

A ideia é não deixar os botões ao lado de cada linha (como colunas da tabela), mas sim selecionar uma linha e depois clicar na opção Editar ou Excluir.

Layout:

[image: Layout]

Minha tabela na View está da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>Grau de Curso</h3>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Ativo</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr class="clickable-row" style="cursor: pointer">
                                    <td >@item.GrauId</td>
                                    <td>@item.Nome</td>
                                    <td>@item.Ativo</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                        <button type="submit" name="novo" id="novo" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Novo</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="editar" id="editar" class="btn btn-w-m btn-warning" data-toggle="#modal">Editar</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="excluir" id="excluir" class="btn btn-w-m btn-danger" data-toggle="modal">Excluir</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ao clicar no botão Novo, consigo abrir normalmente o Modal. Segue código do Modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("InserirGrau", "Curso", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cadastrar Grau de Curso</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group" onload="document.txtnome.focus()">
                            @Html.Label("Nome: ", new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label", @for = "inputNome" })
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                @Html.TextBox("txtNome", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "inputNome", @autofocus = "" })<br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="salvar" name="salvar" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Para selecionar a linha na table e muda-la de cor estou usando o seguinte script:

```
            $('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function (event) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1) Como obter e repassar ao Script o ID do objeto selecionado?

2) Após obter este ID, como abrir o modal pelo botão Editar ou Excluir repassando os dados do Objeto.

Agradeço muito a atenção.

Arthur

---

**COMPLEMENTO**

Dúvida a partir da resposta do colega [AL_Mauricio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/90885/al-mauricio):

1. Criei um botão Detalhe na view Index para executar o script que abre o modal com os detalhes do objeto.
2. Coloquei o data-val="@item.GrauId" na table da view Index.
3. Criei uma Action no Controller chamada Detalhes que recebe o ID passado pelo Script e busca no Banco de dados o objeto, devolvendo para view Detalhes o objeto localizado.
4. Criei uma view chamada Detalhes sem layout, apenas com parte do Modal a ser exibido, que exibe os dados recebidos do objeto enviado pela Action.

O botão Detalhe está abrindo o modal, porém está passando o ID vazio para o Controller.

Aparentemente é um erro no meu Script, que não está pegando o id do data-val.

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function (event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }

        $(".detalhe").click(function Detalhes() {
            var id = $('.clickable-row .active').attr('data-val');
            $("#modal").load("Detalhes?id=" + id, function () {
                $("#modal").modal();
            })
        });

    });
```

---

**SOLUÇÃO**

Após as respostas dos colegas [AL_Mauricio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/90885/al-mauricio) e [edCosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64518/edcosta) e pesquisas no StackOverflow cheguei a seguinte solução do Script para pegar o Id e repassar para a ActionResult.

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function (event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            var id = $(this).data('val');
        }

        $(".detalhe").click(function Detalhes() {
            $("#modal").load("Detalhes?id=" + id, function () {
                $("#modal").modal();
            })
        });
    });
```

ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(string id)
    {
        int num = int.Parse(id);

        //Busca do Objeto e retorno para View Detalhes (modal)
    }
```

Valeu!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar um data-val na sua tr com o valor do id do objeto, assim ao clicar no botão você conseguirá pegar o id do elemento e enviar para sua função que exclui ou edita.

Exemplo

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Ativo</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr class="clickable-row" data-val="@item.GrauId" style="cursor: pointer">
                                    <td >@item.GrauId</td>
                                    <td>@item.Nome</td>
                                    <td>@item.Ativo</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Para você pegar o valor depois basta usar o jquery e pegar o atributo data-val

```
function Excluir(){
var GrauIdSelected =$('.clickable-row .active').attr('data-val');
//faça algo para excluir
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Atualizei minha pergunta com a solução encontrada.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a parte complementar

Como vc utiliza parâmetros na ActionResult Detalhes (modal), então o certo a se passar seria

```
$("#modal").load("Detalhes/" + id, function () {
                $("#modal").modal();
})


public ActionResult Detalhes(string ID)
{
  // Resto da logica
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Atualizei minha pergunta com a solução encontrada.